# Root of function involving trig and exponential

Tags: trigonometry, roots

Would anyone know an analytical solution to finding the root of

$$
f(x) = \sin(x^2) - e^x
$$

in $[-1,1]$?  I'm writing a simple root finding program and thought I'd try this as a test case, but stumped myself trying to find a root to compare with!

Comment: Try finding the inverse of the function.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there's any closed form. Wolfram Alpha says $x \approx -0.714968969189656...$ is a root in that range; http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=roots+of+sin%28x%5E2%29+-+e%5Ex.